# How correcty evict image cache?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to evict the image cache before take a picture, but it doesn't work and I cannot reupdate an image with the same name because it gives me cache error that the file already exists.

```
          Directory pathCache;
          String pathFile;

            pathCache = await getTemporaryDirectory();
            pathFile = pathCache.path+"/"+profilo+'.jpg';
            print(pathFile);   


try {

               bool res =imageCache.evict(pathFile);
               print("eviction result : $res");

             imageCache.clear();     
             } 
             catch(e) {
             print(e.toString());

             }                
          try {
            // Ensure that the camera is initialized.
            await _initializeControllerFuture;



            // Construct the path where the image should be saved using the
            // pattern package.
            final path = join(
              // Store the picture in the temp directory.
              // Find the temp directory using the `path_provider` plugin.
              (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path,
              profilo+'.jpg',

            );


            // Attempt to take a picture and log where it's been saved.
            await _controller.takePicture(path);
```

What I'm missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to clear only the cache, but the file still exists. You need to do:

1. Remove the old file (from the temporary directory)
2. Clear the cache
3. Take the new picture

```
    File pictureFile = File(path);
    if (pictureFile.existsSync()) {
        pictureFile.deleteSync();
        imageCache.clear();
    }
    ...
    await _controller.takePicture(path);
```